# Substringing from a text a number

Tags: sql, extract

From the following string value of `session` i will like to keep with only the part when the first number big or the last `|` beginning

```
session
nea|fact|za|ninja|web|14ff95092e3x1d214cd2
nea|fact|za|ninja|web|15001274f5ex323c9f96
nea|fact|za|ninja|web|1502897832ax418ecf1a
nea|fact|za|ninja|web|150399c1418x215f0e52
nea|fact|za|ninja|web|1503b3cdf02x386fc450
ta|fact|za|ninja|web|1503b3cdf02x386fc450
ta|fact|za|ninja|web|1503b3cdf02x386fc450
```

expected result

```
14ff95092e3x1d214cd2
15001274f5ex323c9f96
1502897832ax418ecf1a
150399c1418x215f0e52
1503b3cdf02x386fc450
1503b3cdf02x386fc450
1503b3cdf02x386fc450
```

Comment: Which database software are you using? Do all values share the same format or do other values with different arrangements of pipe characters exist?

Comment: there are different length characters until the first number appear, i update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle -

```
SELECT SUBSTR(session, '|', -1)
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

if your db mysql then `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will help you

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(session, "|", -1);
```

Example:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX('nea|fact|za|ninja|web|14ff95092e3x1d214cd2', "|", -1);
returned: 14ff95092e3x1d214cd2
```

In mysql [string related function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

For Sql server your query will be

```
SELECT RIGHT(session , CHARINDEX ('|' ,REVERSE(session))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For sql server:

```
declare @test varchar(1000) = 'nea|fact|za|ninja|web|14ff95092e3x1d214cd2'

SELECT RIGHT(@test , CHARINDEX ('|' ,REVERSE(@test))-1)
```